# Error when getting image out of an array

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, image, parse-platform

I have an array that contains image references such as: <"UIImage: some number>". However, when I try to set the image in my table my app crashes with the following code:

```
    UIImageView *pic = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
pic.image = [pictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The method where the code above resides is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But when I set the variable "pic" equal to "image" which comes from the following code, everything works. I would use this, but I need to save the images from the Parse database in an array to populate my table:

```
       [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {


        if (!error) {

           image= [UIImage imageWithData: pictureData];
           //image is already declared in the implementation.
```

Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: Are the image references in your array the image objectIds from Parse?

Comment: no they are the actual image.

Comment: When your app crashes, what error message does it give?

Comment: @Nil2k15 Post your related code about the `pictures` variable

Comment: I have a few ideas - please post your error and a bit more of your method to help narrow it down!